# Print out entire SOAP request in python spyne server

Tags: python, soap, spyne

I have a SOAP server which is written using `spyne`. Here is the code:

```
class myService(ServiceBase):

    @rpc(Integer, String, _returns=String)
    def my_method(ctx):
        sys.stdout.write("Request for `myService`: {}\n".format(ctx))
        return "0," + "".join(random.sample(string.hexdigits, 16))


application = Application(
    [myService],
    tns=NAMESPACE,
    in_protocol=Soap11(validator="lxml"),
    out_protocol=Soap11()
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger("spyne.util").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(application)
    server = make_server("0.0.0.0", 5555, wsgi_app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

It is a simulator which is going to mock a real service. I connect them with desired clients, but I'm getting `code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type` error for every request. Since I don't have access to the clients who are calling my mock server, I want to print out the received request in my server. Above code does not work (`sys.stdout.write`).

**EDIT 1:**

I changed `sys.stdout` to python `logger`:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("spyne.util")
...
...
...
logger.info("Request for `myService`: {}\n".format(ctx))
```

But nothing is printed and I'm getting following error this time:

```
code 400, message Bad request syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol.xml').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```